# ASP "Validation Requires Jquery"

Tags: asp.net

So I'm basically making a webform probject, But I try to add a field validator to a text box, I've created one on another project but it doesn't request anything it just works on my other one without any errors

But in webforms it says this: http://prntscr.com/3jeanf

Here is my Validation

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"    ControlToValidate="txtReferenceNumber"  CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Must Enter Reference Number!" EnableClientScript="true">Must Enter Reference Number!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: This question is tagged under classic ASP but your control is an ASP.NET control. Please modify your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, from 
[WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for jQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a):

Remove below in web.config if you have

> ```
> <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
> ```

or

> registering jQuery in Global.asax in the Application_Start event like
>   this:
>
> ```
> ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", 
>     new ScriptResourceDefinition
> {
> Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
> DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
> CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
> CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
> });
> ```